# PHP Mysql - Most efficient way to gather data in periods of time and update database?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

My setup goes like this.  I'm having a timed buying period let's say for 10 hours.  I want to gather data in 15 minute periods and update my database to effect the price for the next 15 minutes and so on.  Would I need to use cron jobs for this?  Or is there another route I could take?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also refresh it yourself and use a timer in your browser to refresh the file every fifteen minutes
or 
you may put this cron file to a high trafficked website where a visitor will trigger the cron.

both are fairly easy to setup. Cron would run irregardless of anything and even if your file isn't there the cron will run. But with the other methods you would require the file to be there and and run the cron. One disadvantage is that you would need the page to be open in a browser all the times for the refresh to take place. So it would be better if you have a cron setup. Although page refresh is as easy as doing a meta refresh. One way could be to have an iframe with that cron refreshing every few seconds. This would mean that if there are 100 people online on your website then the cron would be constantly updated by 100 people at set time intervals and even if one page is not loaded properly then there are still other 99 people who have the cron running in an iframe.

Comment: Ok, I want this to all be updated on it's own.  Would it be more difficult having the page refresh in those time intervals or setting up cron jobs for this?

Comment: Ok yeah I think I definitely want to go the cron route.  Is there anything you could point me to on how to execute scripts via cron?

Comment: btw, forgot to mention that you can also use external crons from websites such as http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/ which will reload your webpage externally.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I do.  I want this to be done pretty professionally so doing it in house would be better I think.

Comment: There is a cron generator http://cron.nmonitoring.com/cron-generator.html that you can use to create any cron

Comment: What about the commands to run the cron?  I'm not to sure about that part.